# Unit Digit of A Simplified Fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ is an integer such that $a=xyz4$, where $x,y,z$ are unit digits, and $b$ is a positive integer such that $b=mnp6$, where $m,n,p$ are unit digits, and $a$ and $b$ are not coprime, what are some possible values for the units digit in the numerator and the denominator after $a/b$ has been simplified.

$a/b=dfg2/hjk3$ is one possibility but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: $8884/8886=4442/4443$ so your possibility can happen.

Comment: Hey coffee math, I am trying to deduce certain information about a fraction before simplifying. What information can I extract from the expression?

Comment: Maybe you should add what you're looking for into the question. For example something like: if $(d_1,d_2)$ are the units digits of the numerator and denominator of the simplified fraction, then (i) what pairs $(d_1,d_2)$ can arise this way, and (ii) for each such pair, what are the possible values of $a,b$ which wind up producing that pair.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the units digit.

See, that when units digits are concerned, you have only a limited number of possible values during multiplication. If you want to get $a_1...a_n4$ as when you multiply $b_1...b_m3$ by $c_1...c_lx$, then $x$ will always invariably be 8 $(3×8=24)$.

So, the whole operation will be based off the unit digits.

**Case 1: If the Numerator is Completely Divisible by the Denominator**

$Given,$

${xyz4}\over{mnp6}$

$={{xyz4}\over{6}}$

$Since 6×4=24 & 6×9=54$

$So,$

$\text{The units digit is }4\text{ OR }9$

**Case 2: If the Numerator is not Completely Divisible by the Denominator**

Given that the *a* and *b* are not coprime, they must have a GCD (Which can't be odd since then, they would be even again, and then would have 2 as a common divisor, which would negate the suggestion it's the GCD). Since the digits are 4 and 6, this must have multiple which end with both of those. So let's see those numbers, case by case.

*Case 2.1*

$GCD=x_1...x_n2$

So, by the above process, the number will be ${x_1...x_m2}\over {y_1... y_n3}$

And the unit digits will be$2\over 3$

*Case 2.2*

$GCD=x_1...x_n4$

So, the number will be: 
${x_1...x_m1}\over{y_1... y_n4}$
$OR$
${x_1...x_m1}\over{y_1... y_n9}$
$OR$
${x_1...x_m6}\over{y_1... y_n9}$

And the unit digits will be $1\over 4$ or $1\over9$ or $6\over9$

*Case 2.3*

$GCD=x_1...x_n6$

So, the number will be: 
${x_1...x_m4}\over{y_1... y_n1}$
$OR$
${x_1...x_m9}\over{y_1... y_n1}$
$OR$
${x_1...x_m9}\over{y_1... y_n6}$

And the unit digits will be $4\over 1$ or $9\over1$ or $9\over6$

*Case 2.4*

$GCD=x_1...x_n8$

So, the number will be: 
${x_1...x_m3}\over{y_1... y_n2}$
$OR$
${x_1...x_m3}\over{y_1... y_n7}$
$OR$
${x_1...x_m8}\over{y_1... y_n7}$

And the unit digits will be $3\over 2$ or $3\over7$ or $8\over7$

***So,***

The possible digits are:

**Case 1**

$4,9$

**Case 2**

$2\over3$,$1\over4$,$1\over9$,$6\over9$,$4\over1$,$3\over2$,$3\over7$,$8\over7$